# C# webbrowser can't correctly run the javascript code

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser-control, youtube-javascript-api

My problem is that my webbrowser component can't run the javascript code. If I use IE in that the script works correctly. (I use .net 4.0 framework)

My Javascript code:

```
<div id="player"></div>
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script>
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '200',
          width: '400',
          videoId: '9eh0rAUwZSQ',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
    }
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {      
        if(event.data === 0) {        
            alert('done');
        }
    }
</script>
```

The C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.IO;

namespace two_channel_test
{
  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
  [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]

  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
      public WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();

  public Form1()
      {
          InitializeComponent();

          webBrowser1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
          Controls.Add(webBrowser1);
          Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
      }

      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          webBrowser1.AllowWebBrowserDrop = false;
          webBrowser1.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;
          webBrowser1.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = false;
          webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;
          webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

          StringReader sr;
          sr = new StringReader(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"c:\something\javascriptcode.txt"));        // this is my javascript code what I wrote
          webBrowser1.DocumentText = sr.ReadToEnd();
      }

      public void Test()
      {
          MessageBox.Show("Working...", "client code");
      }
  }
}
```

Have you any idea what is wrong with my code?

Comment: I'm sorry for the javascript code format... :\

Comment: it's strange. The javascript format looks good now... :)

Comment: Does your JavaScript file contains html tags also? Or just the script you presented above?

Comment: I tried with html tags and without them but none of them worked.
If I paste my javascript code here it works correctly:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_inner_html

Comment: Maybe the problem is the translator can't run this part of the code:
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api">

I've got an error:
Error: script error
URL: http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflDCatur/www-widgetapi.js